# How to connect an Android application with IIS server on laptop

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, rest, iis

I have developed an android application which use a C# web service. I have published the web service using IIS server. Now I want to install my application to an Android device and connect it to the WCF rest service running on an IIS server.

What steps should I take to accomplish this?

So far i have used the methods mentioned below. But there are some errors :( Help me fix them!

```
   public String ServiceCallMethod()
    {
    //int x1 = 262, x2 = 525, y1 = 100, y2 = 390;

    String url =     "http://192.168.43.73:85/PathService/PathService.svc/FindPath/"+x1+","+y1+"/"+x2+","+y2+"";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Prepare a request object
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

        // Execute the request
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            // Examine the response status
            Log.i("Praeda",response.getStatusLine().toString());

            // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
            // to worry about connection release

            if (entity != null) {

                // A Simple JSON Response Read
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result= convertStreamToString(instream); // returns error when i debug :(its supposed to return an point array list like this..
    //Response - {"FindPathResult":[{"x":262,"y":165},{"x":346,"y":165},{"x":420,"y":165},{"x":473,"y":165},{"x":473,"y":240},{"x":473,"y":277},{"x":473,"y":320},{"x":473,"y":390},{"x":525,"y":390}]}

    //Instead it returns this
    //<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   // <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     //Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   // <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   // <head>
   // <title>Request Error</title>
   // <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px;  margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
   //</head>
   //<body>
   //<div id="content">
   //<p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
   //<p>The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.</p>
    //</div>
    //</body>
    //</html>
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------



                Log.i("Praeda",result);

                // A Simple JSONObject Creation
                JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result);
                Log.i("Praeda","<jsonobject>\n"+json.toString()+"\n</jsonobject>");

                // A Simple JSONObject Parsing
                JSONArray nameArray=json.names();
                JSONArray valArray=json.toJSONArray(nameArray);
                for(int i=0;i<valArray.length();i++)
                {
                    Log.i("Praeda","<jsonname"+i+">\n"+nameArray.getString(i)+"\n</jsonname"+i+">\n"
                            +"<jsonvalue"+i+">\n"+valArray.getString(i)+"\n</jsonvalue"+i+">");
                    Log.i("TEST","JSONArray Recieved");
                }

                // A Simple JSONObject Value Pushing
                json.put("sample key", "sample value");
                Log.i("Praeda","<jsonobject>\n"+json.toString()+"\n</jsonobject>");

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release

                instream.close();  

              //I want to assign the result to one of my String arrays(this_results) -------------       

              this_result = result;

              //-----------------------------------------------------
              System.out.println(" End of ServiceCallMethod() ");
                return result;

            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
         * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
         * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
         * and returned as String.
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

And this is my WCF Rest Get method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using testServer;

namespace IGTSMPathService
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name     "PathService" in code, svc and config file together.
public class PathService : IPathService
{
    //GET Method 
    //http://localhost:50837/PathService.svc/FindPath/262,100/525,390
    //Response - {"FindPathResult":[{"x":262,"y":165},{"x":346,"y":165},{"x":420,"y":165},  {"x":473,"y":165},{"x":473,"y":240},{"x":473,"y":277},{"x":473,"y":320},{"x":473,"y":390},{"x":525,"y":390}]}

    public System.Drawing.Point[] FindPath(string cLocation, string destination)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point[] list;
        Location loc = new Location(cLocation);
        System.Drawing.Point cur, des;
        cur = new System.Drawing.Point(Int32.Parse(cLocation.Split(',')[0].Trim()),    Int32.Parse(cLocation.Split(',')[1].Trim()));
        des = new System.Drawing.Point(Int32.Parse(destination.Split(',')[0].Trim()),   Int32.Parse(destination.Split(',')[1].Trim()));
        list = loc.findPoint(cur, des);

        return list;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use wrappers for your service methods like this:
For POST:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   Method = "POST",
   UriTemplate = "login")]
```

For GET:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   Method = "GET",
   UriTemplate = "users/{userId}")]
```

In your android application use any example of work with web-services, but use ip of your IIS server (be sure that IIS server is availeble by wi-fi from device)

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) Actually i have completed my web service and the mobile application.i just wanna know the STEPS that i should take to connect my android phone/application to the IIS server. :)

Comment: @Ruby Please approve my answer :)

Comment: In a contract for your WCF service